# Prove that $1+e^{\frac{-1}{x}}+2x(e^{\frac{-1}{x}}-1) >0 $ when $x >0$

Tags: calculus, functions, inequality

I've tried to prove that
$$1+e^{-1/x}+2x(e^{-1/x} - 1)>0$$
whenever $ x>0$ .

**My attempt**: By setting $f(x) =1+e^{\frac{-1}{x}}+2x(e^{\frac{-1}{x}}-1)$ and then I tried to see where is the minimum, and if it is above the x-axis. But I couldn't get to a result because I got stuck on $f'(x) $, especially on how to know the solutions of $f'(x) =0$. I guess I can use numerical methods to solve the equation, but it isn't allowed to use numerical methods in this problem, so is there a method other than working on f(x), like, you know, the old original way to prove inequalities without using fucntions and calculus?

Comment: Hint: The inequality is written as $\mathrm{e}^{-1/x} > \frac{2x - 1}{1 + 2x}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=1+e^{-1/x}+2x\left(e^{-1/x}-1\right)\\
f'(x)=\frac{2x^2+2x+1}{x^2}e^{-1/x}-2\\
f''(x)=\frac{e^{-1/x}}{x^4}>0$$
Hence, $f'$ is strictly increasing in the interval $(0,\infty)$. Since
$\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=2\cdot1-2=0$,
$f'(x)<0$ for all $x>0$ and $f$ is strictly decreasing in the interval $(0,\infty)$. Finally, since $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=0$, $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$. You can calculate the last limit with a first-order series expansion of $e^{-1/x}$:
$$e^{-1/x}=1-\frac{1}{x}+O(x^{-2})\quad(x\to\infty) $$

Answer (score 1):

$f'(x) \text{ as limit } x\to \pm \infty f'(x) \to 0$ also this
$f'(x)$ shows this is increasing function for $x \in (-\infty, 0)$ and decreasing for $(0, \infty)$ thus take limit as $$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}f(x)  = 0$$